# Что это за кэш?

Tags: css, css3, scss, шрифты

**На сайте Icomoon сделать иконочный шрифт и в исходниках в пути к шрифту было это "?r3waic".**

Подскажите пожалуйста что это за кэш? Что будет если без него использовать шрифт и вообще как правильно поступить в верстке.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Icomoon';
  src:  url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/Icomoon.eot?r3waic');
  src:  url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/Icomoon.eot?r3waic#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/Icomoon.ttf?r3waic') format('truetype'),
    url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/Icomoon.woff?r3waic') format('woff'),
    url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/Icomoon.svg?r3waic#Icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'Icomoon' !important;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

**Итог: Мне нужно понять как использовать этот кэш.**

Comment: а это штука не удаляется `?r3waic` ?

Comment: удаляется, но тогда иконочный шрифт без этого кэша не работает.

Comment: у меня ни разу такого не было .. работало всегда без этого Кэш

Comment: Этот-то не нужно удалять, достаточно было отредактировать. Восстановил, убрал вторую часть. )

Comment: На счет удаление кэша "?r3waic" в пути и подключения, то шрифт все же работает, но не понятно принадлежность этого кэша.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все из-за того, как в браузерах работает кеш.

[Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/) - генерируемый шрифт с иконками. Представьте ситуацию, когда в уже используемый у себя на сайте пак вы добавляете пару иконок. Добавили, сгенерировали файлы шрифтов, обновили их на хостинге. Но названия файлов остались те же (`Icomoon.ttf` и т.д.).

Что же будет, если в стилях будут прямые ссылки на файлы?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Icomoon';
  src:  url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/Icomoon.eot');
  src:  url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/Icomoon.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/Icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/Icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
    url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/Icomoon.svg#Icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Браузер скачает `Icomoon.ttf` и закеширует. После добавления пары иконок файлы вы обновили, но название файла не изменилось. И ссылки на них не изменились. Браузер это видит - и использует старые кешированные версии файлов.

Как дать браузеру понять, что файлы изменились? Варианта два:

- Менять имена файлов (так, например, работают [ассеты в Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark));
- Добавлять к ссылкам случайный параметр, который менять вместе с файлами.

У вас - второй случай. Параметр `r3waic` - случайно сгенерированная строка. При перегенерации шрифтов сайт Icomoon должен выдать вам новые стили с новым псевдослучайно сгенерированным параметром, например с `vf41cd`.

В итоге ссылки на файлы "изменятся", и браузер скачает новые версии файлов, вместо того, чтобы взять старые из кеша.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как учитывать этот момент при написании миксина? И где в спецификации прописан этот момент, то есть как парсер понимает к чему относиться эта строчка и как она относиться к самому шрифту(она внутри шрифта где - то прописана "r3waic")?

Comment: Нет, внутри шрифта нигде не прописана. Я обычно просто добавляю ко всем подобным ссылкам параметр `?v=22`, и когда мне нужно - увеличиваю `22` на единичку вверх.

Comment: то есть по сути этот текст не несет ни какой смысловой нагрузки. он нужен что бы просто браузер увидел разницу между кэшированной ссылки и новой. я правильно понял?

Comment: Да, именно так, все верно.

Comment: `url("../fonts/Exo2/Exo2-Bold/Exo2-Bold.svg#Exo 2") format("svg"); }` вы не подскажите зачем у `svg` в конце пути `#Exo`?