# Почему scss так компилирует переменные?

Tags: css, css3, scss, шрифты

**Этот вопрос касается Icomoon в целом.**

Не могу разобраться почему scss так компилит символы, но они работают, если в пути к шрифту указан не только шрифт, но и кэш шрифта.

Связанный вопрос: [что это за кэш?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/672152/)

```css
$icomoon-font-path: "fonts" !default;
$icon-bell: "\e900";
$icon-like: "\e901";
$icon-paceholder: "\e902";
$icon-search: "\e903";
$icon-star: "\e904";
$icon-vision: "\e905";
$icon-vision-off: "\e906";
$icon-angle-left: "\e907";
$icon-angle-right: "\e908";
$icon-arrow-right: "\e909";
$icon-angle-bottom: "\e90a";
$icon-chat-angle-bottom: "\e90b";
$icon-chat-angle-top: "\e90c";
```

```css
@import "variables";

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Icomoon';
  src:  url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/Icomoon.eot?r3waic');
  src:  url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/Icomoon.eot?r3waic#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/Icomoon.ttf?r3waic') format('truetype'),
    url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/Icomoon.woff?r3waic') format('woff'),
    url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/Icomoon.svg?r3waic#Icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'Icomoon' !important;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-bell {
  &:before {
    content: $icon-bell;
  }
}
.icon-like {
  &:before {
    content: $icon-like;
  }
}
.icon-paceholder {
  &:before {
    content: $icon-paceholder;
  }
}
.icon-search {
  &:before {
    content: $icon-search;
  }
}
.icon-star {
  &:before {
    content: $icon-star;
  }
}
.icon-vision {
  &:before {
    content: $icon-vision;
  }
}
.icon-vision-off {
  &:before {
    content: $icon-vision-off;
  }
}
.icon-angle-left {
  &:before {
    content: $icon-angle-left;
  }
}
.icon-angle-right {
  &:before {
    content: $icon-angle-right;
  }
}
.icon-arrow-right {
  &:before {
    content: $icon-arrow-right;
  }
}
.icon-angle-bottom {
  &:before {
    content: $icon-angle-bottom;
  }
}
.icon-chat-angle-bottom {
  &:before {
    content: $icon-chat-angle-bottom;
  }
}
.icon-chat-angle-top {
  &:before {
    content: $icon-chat-angle-top;
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, теперь хорошо. Ещё один плюс вам. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sass при компиляции `utf-8` юникод файлов - переводит подобные вашим последовательности в юникод-символы. Почему вы видите квадраты вместо символов в редакторе? Потому что в вашем моноширинном шрифте эти символы не отрисованы. Но они отрисованы в шрифте Icomoon, который подключается на сайте, и там в итоге символы корректно отображаются.

Резюмируя: Это нормальное поведение, и по поводу скомпилированных символов беспокоиться не стоит.

> Однако, если вдруг ваши файлы хранятся в `ASCII`-кодировке - Sass все равно будет компилировать символы в них, хотя по логике - не должен. На гитхабе уже 3 года [висит открытый тикет по теме](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1395). Можно почитать, но разумный способ решения - перевести свои стили в `utf-8`-кодировку.

Answer (score 1):

Это известная бага, можно экранировать, например так:

```
$icon-like: "e901";

@function unicode($str) {
  @return unquote("\"")+unquote(str-insert($str, "\\", 1))+unquote("\"");
}

.icon-like {
  &:before {
    content: unicode($icon-like);
  }
}
```

А ещё достаточно компактно и изящно получается, если использовать списки, а не отдельные переменные:

```
$icons: ( 
  bell: "e900",
  like: "e901",
  paceholder: "e902",
  search: "e903",
  star: "e904",
  vision: "e905",
  vision-off: "e906",
  angle-left: "e907",
  angle-right: "e908"
);

@each $name, $str in $icons {
  .icon-#{$name}:before {
    content: unquote("\"")+unquote(str-insert($str, "\\", 1))+unquote("\"");
  }
}
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста пояснить почему так происходит?
$icon-bell: "#{\e900}"; (sccs) => .icon-bell:before {content: "\\e900";}

Я не понимаю почему там две "\\" и что это такое ("\""). Как раз за одно поясните эту строчку.
content: unquote("\"")+unquote(str-insert($str, "\\", 1))+unquote("\"");
Буду вам очень признателен.

Comment: вроде разобрался и заметил что второй unquote не нужен, ибо unquote("\"") + "e22" = "e22, то есть при конкатенации с результатом метода unquote у правого операнда пропадают ("").

Comment: обратный слэш экранирует следующий за ним символ

Comment: метод unquote("\"") удаляет кавычки и результат будет ".
" + "e22" = "e22. Почему так выходит? На счет обратного слэша( обратной косой черты ), он нужен для вызова спецсимволов. "/"" аналогична такой записи "/0022". Я просто не понял почему результат unquote("\"") + "e22" = "e22. http://www.bast-tr.narod.ru/css/css_syntax.html#413